# ORA-14400: - "inserted partition key does not map to any partition"

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have the table with the following colums:

```
foo integer default 0 
'ID', 'INTEGER'
'date','DATE'
'F','VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)'
```

I try to insert the following values:

```
insert into table (foo,id,date,F) values('1','4','01.01.2016','aa');
```

and I get the following error:

> SQL-error: ORA-14400 inserted partition key does not map to any
>   partition
>   14400. 00000 -  "inserted partition key does not map to any partition"
>
> *Cause:    An attempt was made to insert a record into, a Range or Composite
>              Range object, with a concatenated partition key that is beyond
>              the concatenated partition bound list of the last partition -OR-
>              An attempt was made to insert a record into a List object with
>              a partition key that did not match the literal values specified
>              for any of the partitions.
>   *Action:   Do not insert the key. Or, add a partition capable of accepting
>              the key, Or add values matching the key to a partition specification

What did I do wrong?

**UPDATE:**

```
call meta_ddl.create_table  ('table1','create table table1 (foo integer default 0)  $#TABLEOPTIONS#$');
call meta_ddl.add_column    ('table1','ID', 'INTEGER');
call meta_ddl.add_column_with_default('table1','DATE','DATE', 'SYSDATE', 1);
call meta_ddl.add_column    ('table1','F','VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)');
```

Comment: Presumably, you failed to set up a partition to hold the value that you're trying to insert into the table. But as the question is missing details of how you partitioned the table, you'd either have to investigate it yourself or update your question with the full table description (including partitioning clauses).

Comment: Please add the full DDL (CREATE statement) of the relevant table to your question.

Comment: @Codo  I have updated

Comment: What is $#TABLEOPTIONS#$?

Comment: I doubt this is the entire DDL. Your table must have partitions. Is is hidden in `$#TABLEOPTIONS#$`?

Answer (score 1):

Columns "foo" and "id" are integer types, no need to add the single ticks around them on an insert.  Not sure if this is causing your specific issue, but it can't help.

```
insert into table (foo,id,date,F) values(1,4,'01.01.2016','aa');
```

You may also be trying to insert a value that's outside a partition range.  I've seen this happen before with date ranges.  But we can't answer that unless you post the table definition.

Comment: That was not the problem. I have updated the question